# Understanding Projection operator $\pi$

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projection

I know that the projection function $\pi_{i}(x)=a_{i}$

where $x=(a_{1}, a_{2}, \cdots a_{n})$ is a point in the n dimensional space defined by the cartesian product $A_{1} \times A_{2} \times \cdots A_{n}$ and $a_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ coordinate of  $x$. Source: https://solitaryroad.com/c787.html

Then what does $\pi_{[-c,c]^{n}}(z)$ mean?

where $[-c, c]^{n} = [-c,c] \times\cdots [-c,c]$ and c is always positive.

Comment: A bit more context might help; what are the domain and codomain of this map? Can you quote an excerpt where this notation is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the projection of the point $z$ onto the cube $[-c,c]\times[-c,c]\times\cdots\times[-c.c]$.  So, if $z=(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n)$ are the co-ordinates of $z$, for each co-ordinate you get $z_i$ if $z_i\in [-c,c]$ and $0$ otherwise.  As an example, suppose $n=3$ and $z=(5,-2,1.5)$.  Then $\pi_{[-2,2]^3}(z) = (0,-2, 1.5)$

Note that normally a projection is looking at an object with more dimensions that the space being projected to, but it's not necessary